# Firestore get array data at index 0

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Below I have some data in firestore.[image]

I have a an array in the _geoloc field. Each of those indexes have latitude and longitude coordinates. So using SWIFT I want to be able to only get the lat and lng coordinates at index 0 and pass them to individually to a string.  I have been researching for days and I am stuck.  I have tried to create a new array of strings or an AnyObject array and I just get stuck with retrieving the data I need at index 0, and passing only those 2 lat/lng coordinates to string values.  I have several failed snippets of code I could post.

Here is a snippet of what I was attempting to do: (I am really new to firebase so the code is a bit ugly as I am just trying to figure this out)

```
        Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document("626").getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document {
//            let geo_array = document["_geoloc"]

            var yourArray = [String]()
           // let geo_location = [geo_array] as [AnyObject]
            let array: [Any] =  document["_geoloc"] as! [Any]
            let tmpArray = array.map({ return String(describing: $0)})
            let string = tmpArray.joined(separator: ",")
           yourArray.append(string)

            print(yourArray[0])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to cast your object from Any to an array of dictionaries and get the first property:

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document("626").getDocument { document, error in
    if let document = document {
        var yourArray: [String] = []    
        if let location = (document["_geoloc"] as? [[String:Double]])?.first,
            let latitude = location["lat"],
            let longitude = location["lon"] {
            let coordinate2d = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude) 
            yourArray.append("Latitude: \(location.latitude), Longitude: \(location.Longitude)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I see, I was declaring my array wrong. This answers my question and I will mark it, but as a follow up, if I wanted to get the second, third, or even 10th index, what would be the right syntax for that?  `[[String:Double]])?[2]` is not correct.

Comment: Just remove the first property you will have an array of dictionaries. You can map them as needed. Right now I am on my mobile but I will edit the post once I get a chance.

Comment: I figured it out, I was referencing the index at the wrong spot.

      `if let location = (document["_geoloc"] as? [[String:Double]]),
            let latitude = location[1]["lat"] {`
Appreciate the help @leo-dabus, apparently I need to hit the swift books and get better educated on arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe first declare this:

```
  var firstPositionValues = [AnyObject]()
```

Then get it like this:

```
let db = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document("626")

 db.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document {

            let geo_location = document["_geoloc"] as [AnyObject] // <- this is all of them in the document
            var initialValues = geo_location[0] // <- here are your lat and lng at position 0
             self.firstPositionValues = initialValues

        }
```

Hope I understood correctly good luck.